# regex with no URL context path

Tags: regex

I want to have the regex check if there is no context path in the URL so that i can handle it in a different backend.

www.mydomain.com & www.mydomain.com/ --- REGEX check needed.
www.mydomain.com/abc or www.mydomain.com/def/ghi/ijk - should not fall under the above Regex check

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work for you,

```
^(https?:\/\/)?[^\/]+\/?$
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/0gXbS4/1

As per comment , see the negation of ‛-‛

```
^(https?:\/\/)?[^\/-]+\/?$
```

Comment: It almost worked but i have the domain like https://abc-def.domain.com. Can you please suggest what would that be.

Comment: h t t p s://abc-def.domain.com

Comment: @DevOpsNewB, see answer again to negate (-) sign